# How to make jQuery tabs-btn default closed

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I'm using code to hide/show div from link:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.tabs').myTabs({
    // container of navigation inside '.tabs'
    nav: '.tab-btns',
    // container of contents inside '.tabs'
    tabs: '.tab-contents'
  });
});

$.fn.myTabs = function(settings) {
  return this.each(function() {

    /*
save cached version of the first elements inside the containers. by calling the first elements of each container you are not limitng the plugin user to any specific class or elememt.
*/
    var btns = $(settings.nav, this).children(),
      tabs = $(settings.tabs, this).children();


    /* we relying on the order of the elements as the conection between the buttons and the tabs  
notice that .each() get the index of the btn..
we are useinf it to find the current tab.
*/

    btns.each(function(index) {
      var btn = $(this),
        tab = tabs.eq(index);


      btn.click(function(e) {
        /* prevent unnesscry work by checking if the button clicked is already active  */
        if (btn.is('.active')) return false;

        /* notice that first filter to find the last 'active' button before we remove the 'active' class  otherwise it remove the class for every button. unnesscry work prevented again */
        btns.filter('.active').removeClass('active');

        /* hide previus tab.. */
        tabs.filter(':visible').hide();

        btn.addClass('active');
        tab.show();


        return false;
      });
    });

    // emulate click on the first tab button;
    btns.first().click();
  });
};
```

```css
.tab-btns .active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <nav class="tab-btns">
    <a href="#tab1">tab btn 1</a>
    <a href="#tab2">tab btn 2</a>
    <a href="#tab3">tab btn 3</a>
    <a href="#tab4">tab btn 4</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="tab-contents">
    <div id="tab1">tab content 1</div>
    <div id="tab2">tab content 2</div>
    <div id="tab3">tab content 3</div>
    <div id="tab4">tab content 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to make 'navigation' divs (tabs tbn1 etc.) hidden by default?

Comment: You are clicking the first tab programmatically, (`btns.first().click();`) then what exactly are you expecting to do?

Comment: I'd love to not to do it but when I delete:    btns.first().click();
  }); it doesn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: Unfortunately posted reply too fast

Comment: Code displays whole content from all divs (hidden divs) which I wanted to show after clicking them. I just want to have them hidden by default

Comment: Sorry, but still it is unclear. Is it possible for you to explain with an example, I am ready to solve it. `:)`

Comment: Thank you in advance. I made this js bin out of the code I'm using:
http://jsbin.com/gagebixuha/edit?html,css,js,output
At the end of JS theres a line I deleted.
I don't know how to use js because I'm rather designer than programmer and trying figure out 'how its made'.

Comment: Man, the link doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this :

```
 $('.tab-contents').find('div:not(":first")').hide(); // if you want to hide all divs except for 1st one.
 $('.tab-contents div').hide(); // if you want to hide all divs 
 $('.tab-btns a').on("click",function()
 {
    $('.tab-contents div').hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).show();
 });
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/kqd7wfLc/5/

It's a very lame way to do things when you already have a build-in API to handle tabs. [jquery Tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/)